# This error makes no-sense, can someone try to solve it

Tags: python, debugging

As I was debugging my code for a shopping list creator I came across an error I couldn't make sense of:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Does anyone know what this means?
The code this was raised over is:

```
for x in stock:
    for y in products:
        print(str(product[y]) + ": " + str(stock[x]))
```

product is a list, stock is a dictionary.

Comment: What are the values in `stock`  and `products`?

Comment: Can you share sample values of `product` and `stock`?

Comment: in product: "apple", "banana", "melon"

Comment: in stock: "apple" = 15, "banana" = 15, "melon" = 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `product` and `stock` are lists, your code should be:

```
for x in stock:
    for y in products:
        print(y + ": " + stock[x])
```

EDIT: If you're trying to print the `stock` amount corresponding to each `product`, you can do:

```
for product in products:
    print(product + ':' + stock[product])
```

**for x in list**: x will take the value of each element in turn, starting from the first element

**for x in dictionary**: x will take the value of each key, you then can access the value with dict[key]

Comment: product is an array

Comment: stock is a dictionary

Comment: Pretty sure product is a *list*.

Comment: In that case, try replacing `x` with `stock[x]` in the snippet I provided.

Comment: yeah a product is a list

Comment: **for x in list**: x will take the value of each element in turn, starting from the first element

**for x in dictionary**: x will take the value of each key, you then can access the value with dict[key]

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the products in the product list and get the value of the stock dict with name in the product list.

```
for p in products:
    print(p + ": " + str(stock[p]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the last line to

```
print(str(y) + ": " + str(stock[x]))
```

And since both hold `str` type you can get rid of the `str()` as well:

```
print(y + ": " + stock[x])
```

A `for` loop gives the `variable` the elements of the `list` and *not its indices*